# Tomcat Won't Start

Tags: tomcat, raspberry-pi

I installed Tomcat on a Raspberry Pi I got, and everything was working great. However, yesterday, it seemed to stop working. The first thing that I noticed, was that when I attempted to run the startup script, I got the following error...

```
touch: cannot touch `/opt/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs/catalina.out': Permission denied
/opt/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/catalina.sh: 391: /opt/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /opt/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

This hadn't happened before, but whatever...I did a chmod catalina.out and the error went away. Unfortunately, I wasn't having any luck hitting the Tomcat manager (ie. :8080). I looked at the output from the startup script and noticed that JRE home was set to /usr, which didn't seem right, so I changed the Tomcat startup script to point JRE_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-armhf. I still can't access the Tomcat manager, though. Furthermore when I look at the processes running on my Pi, Tomcat is nowhere to be found.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you change any folder permissions? which user does tomcat run under?

Comment: No, I didn't change any permissions, so I really don't understand why I started to get that error all of a sudden...as I said, I had already successfully started Tomcat several times. Everything in my Tomcat bin folder is owned by root, so I'm assuming that's the user it would run under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an alias to run the startup script, and forgot to include sudo before the path to the script. Doh!